# Python bytearray.fromhex() not expected value

Tags: python, arrays

I'm very new to Python and I looking to extract hex bytes values from a string.

Here a sample of code that produce an output that I not expect:

```
    my_str1 = 'AA001404'
    my_ba1 = bytearray.fromhex(my_str1)
    my_str2 = 'AA007236'
    my_ba2 = bytearray.fromhex(my_str2)
    print(my_str1)
    print(my_ba1)
    print(my_str2)
    print(my_ba2)
```

My output is

```
AA001404
bytearray(b'\xaa\x00\x14\x04')
AA007236
bytearray(b'\xaa\x00r6')
```

But I was expected

```
AA001404
bytearray(b'\xaa\x00\x14\x04')
AA007236
bytearray(b'\xaa\x00\x72\x36')
```

Can someone explain me the "r6" I obtain, and how to proceed to get the byte array I expect?

Comment: Python is printing the hexadecimal form of values that are not printable. 0x72 in the ASCII table is lowercase 'r', 0x36 is '6'

Answer (score 0):

@adenomian  : output is printing the character values of hex equivalent.

Let's say 72 hex value in character is r so that is why in your output instead of 72 you have seen character 'r'

clear explanation is given in the below IBM article for the same :

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ste/8.4.1?topic=information-hex-decimal-symbol-values

[Refer the ibm article]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).